# how to check out from an svn that requires "callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt"?

Tags: ros, svn, rosinstall, mit-ros-pkg, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing Kinect Demos for DiamondBack,follow the instruction here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/dback

and I get stucked on step 5:

Check out the mit-ros-pkg code, as well as other needed libraries using rosinstall:

```
rosinstall ~/kinect_demos /opt/ros/diamondback kinect_demos.rosinstall
```

I got error msgs like this

```
Installing https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk  to /home/azureviolin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg
Failed to checkout from url https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk : callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt required
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/home/azureviolin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg'
 Checkout of https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk version  into /home/azureviolin/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg failed.
```

So my question is, how to neglect this callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt and check out the svn anyway? Or, how to get this trust so that I can check out the svn?

---

I searched and found this https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3169

it says "mit-ros-pkg has a self-signed certificate, which means that SVN creates a prompt for checkout. You can override this in svn with '--non-interactive --trust-server-cert'. This doesn't seem like the right default option, but it would be nice to have an option in rosinstall that forces this. Otherwise we cannot rosdoc mit-ros-pkg w/o manually checking it out on every build machine "

but rosinstall doesn't have the option of "--non-interactive --trust-server-cert"

---

my OS is Ubuntu 10.04, with DiamondBack.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28170/how-to-check-out-from-an-svn-that-requires-%22callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt%22-?/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked a friend about svn, and solved this problem.

type the following in terminal:

```
svn checkout https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/trunk/kinect_utils/
```

and you can choose to trust the certificate manually. **the url after "svn check" can be anything under the same svn you want to get certificate.**

In this case, do svn checkout once, delete the files that downloaded to your ~/ , and re-run rosinstall in step 5.  it might take a while , but everything should be fine. You'll see " rosinstall update compelete." at last.

---

Originally posted by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) with karma: 67 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0